# fix problems with strings in kivymd

Tags: python, string, kivy

Hi there I having a problem and i dont understand what it is?
but i think that the problem is on the variable sth, it works without the var variable but is there something that make it works like that?

Here is my code:

KV:

```
<Main>
    product: product

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .7}
        spacing: dp(100)
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: product
            hint_text: 'Enter a product'
            icon_left: 'magnify'
            on_text_validate: app.System() 

    FloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: .43, .3
            height: self.minimum_height
            pos_hint: {"x": .05, "y": .35}

            BoxLayout:
                id: box
                size_hint_y: None
                height: dp(150)

                MDLabel:
                    text: app.sth
```

PY:

```
class Main(MDApp):
    Window.size = (310, 520)
    title = "Best Price"
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    sth = StringProperty()
    var = "This is a message"

    def System(self):
        self.sth = self.var



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

here is the error:

```
     self.sth = self.var
     File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in 
     kivy.properties.Property.__set__
     File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 541, in kivy.properties.Property.set
     File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 532, in kivy.properties.Property.set
     File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 698, in 
     kivy.properties.StringProperty.check
     ValueError: Main.sth accept only str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with kivy but from my understanding of the error log, it seems that the `sth` variable is being assigned a value of type other than string.

Can you try setting the `self.sth = "checl"` and see if that works?

Update:

From the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html), it suggests initialize the object with default value

```
class MyClass(EventDispatcher):
    my_string = StringProperty("default")
```

Can you try initializing it with some string and then see if you code above works.

Comment: yes I know that, but is there any other way that you can put the strings in a variable?

Comment: perhaps can you try declaring the variable inside the system() method and see if that works.

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify have you tried changing the following code `StringProperty()` to `StringProperty("something")` and executing your code above. Does that still give the same error? From what's shown in the doc here (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) all I can imagine is that the variable `var` is being set to a different type.

Comment: Can you also try this, set the value in variable `var` to use a single quotation rather than double. So it should become var = `'This is a message'`.

Comment: Great to hear. It looks like its that single vs double quotation issue in python.